# Seeking Android app to save offline map and POIs?

Tags: software-recommendations, android, point-of-interest

I don't know much about GIS and would like to find an application for travelling with the following features:

- support Points of Interests (sights, restaurants, etc.); Clicking on any POI should display a pop-up with a bit of information (eg. address, history of a building, etc.)
- download maps for offline use, so that no data connection is required
- should display the user's current location using GPS. Apparently, a data connection is not required to use GPS, although it might speed things up when enabling GPS

Are there Android applications that can do this?

That would make it easier to travel rather than carrying infos on paper.

---

Android Google Maps doesn't support layers for offline maps, so adding one's locations through the web Google Maps won't work.

Users recommended [MapsWithMe](http://mapswith.me/en/home) which is supposed to support "bookmarks" in the Pro version. If someone uses the Pro version, can you confirm that locations are downloaded and saved in offline maps?

Also, is it possible to build a list on a PC through eg. Google Maps/MapsEngine, and tell MapsWithMe Pro to download it?

E-mails to the author (info@, support@, and android@) returned no reply.

Answer (score 2):

I recently used [Locus Map Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus) on trip to collect POIs.

This App has the ability to [download and use offline](http://www.locusmap.eu/dt_portfolio/offline-maps/) Maps. If you download or create vector maps in [Mapsforge's compact map format](http://download.mapsforge.org/), you can use that in this app as well.